# Transfer a matrix with repeated eigenvalues into its Jordan canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & -9\\
1 & -3
\end{bmatrix}$ and I want transform it into Jordan Canonical Form, i.e. I want to find a $P$ which puts $A$ into Jordan Canonical Form $J$.
\begin{equation}
J = P^{-1}AP
\end{equation}

I know that $J = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, meaning that $A$ is not diagonalizable. Therefore $P$ should be composed of an eigenvector of $A$ ($e_1$) and a generalized eigenvector ($e_2$). So,

$P = [e_1 \quad e_2]$

$e_1 = [3 \quad 1]^T$

The generalized eigenvector should lie null space of $(A - \lambda_2I)^2$ which is $A^2$. Since $A^2$ is all zero matrix, I can choose $e_2$ whatever I want. When I choose it as $[0 \quad 1]^T$, $J$ turn out to be $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -3\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ which is not I want. I cannot figure out why this is the case.

Comment: "Putting $J$ into Jordan Canonical Form" is not the same as "diagonalizing". Diagonalizing will certainly give you the JCF (which will be diagonal), but we don't call the process "diagonalization" when the result is not a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, okay maybe I should say "almost diagonal".

Comment: You should say "transform into its Jordan canonical form".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thanks now I changed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose $e_2$ to be whatever you want, but then you want $e_1$ to be equal to $(A-\lambda I)e_2$; otherwise, it doesn't work. You can't just pick an arbitrary $e_1$ and have it work for an arbitrary $e_2$.

(Note also that you don't just want $e_2$ in the nullspace of $(A-\lambda I)^2$; you also want it to **not** be in the nullspace of $A-\lambda I$.)

If you want to pick $e_2$ to be $(0,1)^T$, then you want $e_1 = Ae_2 = (-9,-3)^T$, which is precisely $-3$ times your original $e_1$. Alternatively, since your $e_2$ gave you $Ae_2 = -3e_1$, then replace it with $f_2=-\frac{1}{3}e_2$ so that you get $Af_2 = -\frac{1}{3}(-3e_1) = e_1$.